# Convert date retrieved from ntp server with python

Tags: python, date, format, ntp

Is it possible to convert time retrieved from NTP server  (with python script) in this format "Wed Jul 13 00:17:58 CEST 2011" to this format "2011-07-13 00:18:10"

```
    client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    data = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'
    client.sendto(data, (ntp.server.com,123))
    data, address = client.recvfrom( 1024 )
    if data:
        utc_secs = struct.unpack('!12I', data)[10]
        utc_secs -= 2208988800L
        utc_secs = time.ctime(utc_secs)
        print utc_secs
        return utc_secs
```

I get this format : "Wed Jul 13 00:17:58 CEST 2011"

I want to convert this into this format "2011-07-13 00:17:58" ( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' )

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you can go directly from the number of seconds to the time format you desire; however I will explain the general solution before the exact snippet for your case at the bottom.

In general this type of problem is solved with the help of [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) and [strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime). You should also refer to the [formatting codes](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) in the python docs.

`strptime()` matches the pieces of a date string and creates a python time structure. `strftime()` can then be used to convert that time structure into whatever format you desire.

```
from datetime import datetime
ntp_time = datetime.strptime(time_str_from_ntp, "%a %b %y %H:%M:%S")
formatted_time = datetime.strftime(ntp_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Or in your particular case, you can replace

```
utc_secs = time.ctime(utc_secs)
```

with (NOTE: if you have not done `from datetime import datetime` then you should use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` below and not simply `datetime.fromtimestamp`)

```
formatted_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(utc_secs).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: I don't know if this was correct in 2011, but I think the line for ntp_time = ... in the first code block should be corrected to
```ntp_time = datetime.strptime(time_str_from_ntp, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> sec #your utc_secs
1310511730
>>> time.ctime(sec) #instead of this
'Wed Jul 13 02:02:10 2011'
>>> d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sec) #do this
>>> d   
datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 13, 2, 2, 10)
>>> d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2011-07-13 02:02:10'
```