# Date Time convert from CSV to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have a CSV file which i am loading into MySQL DB, one of the fields is DataTime in NTP time format ex: **10:14:18.531 gmt Wed May 15 2013**  I want to convert it to an acceptable format to store it in MySQL like **2013-05-15 10:14:18**.

Should i do this to the CSV file before start loading it to MySQL or it can be done while loading the CSV file (to locate the NTP column on CSV file and convert it while loading)

I have been told that this can be done using Python please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985312/parsing-date-string-in-python-convert-string-to-date

Comment: Also similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671945/convert-date-retrieved-from-ntp-server-with-python

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your NTP-formatted dates into `datetime` using `strptime` function while loading the CSV file:

```
from datetime import datetime
import MySQLdb


ntp_string = "10:14:18.531 gmt Wed May 15 2013"
ntp_datetime = datetime.strptime(ntp_string, "%H:%M:%S.%f %Z %a %b %d %Y")

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='...', user='...', passwd='...', db='...')
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test (id, mydate) VALUES (%s, %s)', (1, ntp_datetime))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @alecxe,  

Thank you very mush for your useful information.  
I am loading a csv file into MySQL and i was successful using Python using the below script:  

inline `import MySQLdb  

c = db.cursor()  
c.execute("load data local infile '/Users/Desktop/dtest.csv' into table tt lines terminated by '\n'")  `,

My question is how can i use datetime.strptime while loading the CSV file, lets say the NTP field is the 2nd in CSV file.  

Cheers